How can i generate a certificate in Azure Key Vault?
I want to generate a certificate in Azure Key Vault to use on my app services instead of importing a PFX file. Now a few questions , when i click on Generate/Import under Certificates in the Key Vault , it comes up with a screen to fill out some details.
But what is the "Subject" do i need to specify anything there like CN=MyTestWebsite.com ?
The PFX file has organization details and other information.
Also where do i fill out details like Organization Name, address and those other common details ?
I have tried to use the portal but cant see where to do the certificate generation .

To generate ssl-certificate  for app services:
Ensure to configure access policy before creating certificate:

For app services  "Subject: CN = <your_domain_name>".
The components CN (Common Name), O (Organization), L (Locality), S (State or Province), and C (Country) are part of the Distinguished Name (DN) in the subject field of an X.509 certificate. They serve to uniquely identify the entity for which the certificate is issued. This you will set in Subject only.

Output:

Reference:
Create a SSL Certificate in Azure Key Vault

for this , "Subject: CN = <your_domain_name>". can it be any domain or does it have to be for the app service i am using  ?  Where do i get the domain name from ?

@Fiona  It should be a domain name of App Service which are you using

Is your issue get resolved?

I still dont get it , if the app is called Testapp in Azure , would the domain be testapp.azurewebsites.net , so the i would put   Subject: CN = testapp.azurewebsites.net
, is that how it works ?

Also where do i configure access policy ? is it under a user ? Where do i go in Azure , the steps ?  thankyou

Which App Service you are using ?
